# sql query to return number of rows dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of form

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[clientid] [int] NULL,
[startdate] [int] NULL,
[copyid] [int] NULL
```

)

data in the table is of form:

```
 id clientid startdate  copyid
 1       4        11    1
 2       4        12    1
 3       4        44    2
 3       5       123    1
 4       5        15    1
 5       5        12    2
 6       5        12    2
 7       5        12    2
```

the copyid is subset of clientid

My question is that can i form a select query which returns a table with N number of rows
and is a copy of clientid and copyid combination with copyid incremented.

For e.g. it should if clientid is taken as 4 and copyid as 1 and N as 6 it should return 6 rows like

```
  clientid startdate   copyid
  4        11           3
  4        12           3
  4        11           4
  4        12           4
  4        11           5
  4        12           5
```

N will always be a multiple of client and copy combination

I know how to do this using loops. But is it possible using a single select query?

Comment: What should be the value of column copy id in the final result?

Comment: Can you explain the logic that causes the CopyID in the output to start on 3?

Comment: And why is the 3rd row not part of the new output (where clientId = 4 and startdate = 44 (why is a date = 44???)?

Comment: There are two rows in the table with clientid 4 and copyid 1 so i want the query to increment the copyid after evry two rows and its base value should be max(copyid)+1 for that client

Comment: basically i want the clone of client and copy combination with copyid automatically incremented

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's basically datediff from a fixed date

Comment: Then you should call it some kind of offset, not date in the name.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ya I probably should :) Do you think such a query to return the rows dynamically is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a simple cursor.

Using the sample data you gave in the question I created the following solution:

```
DECLARE @ClientID INT = 4 
DECLARE @CopyID INT = 1 
DECLARE @N INT = 6

;WITH DATA 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number () 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY ID)           RN, 
                Count(*) 
                  OVER ( 
                    PARTITION BY CLIENTID) CID 
         FROM   (SELECT *, 
                        Max(COPYID) 
                          OVER ( 
                            PARTITION BY CLIENTID) MaxID, 
                        0                          AS root 
                 FROM   TABLE1)T 
         WHERE  CLIENTID = @clientid 
                AND COPYID = @Copyid), 
     CTE 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   DATA 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t2.[ID], 
                t2.[CLIENTID], 
                t2.[STARTDATE], 
                t2.[COPYID], 
                t2.MAXID, 
                t2.ROOT + 1, 
                t2.RN + T2.CID RN, 
                T2.CID 
         FROM   DATA t1 
                INNER JOIN CTE t2 
                        ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
         WHERE  t2.RN < @N - 1) 
SELECT CLIENTID, 
       STARTDATE, 
       MAXID + ROOT + 1 COPYID 
FROM   CTE 
WHERE  RN <= @N 
ORDER  BY COPYID
```

A working example can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd44c/39).

Comment: Thanks Gidil. I was also thinking to use recursive query using CTE's but since I don't have a very good grip on cte's it would have taken me a very long time to come up with a solution. Thanks again